# ServiceStack Redis C# slow retrieving data

Tags: c#, redis, deserialization, servicestack

I'm using Redis Servicestack in C#. Currently, the way I'm storing data is the following:

```
var listTypedRedis = db.As<MyObject>();

foreach (var obj in myObjects)
{
       listTypedRedis.AddItemToList(listTypedRedis.Lists["urn:list"], obj);
}
```

I successfully store about 6000 records. I have problems retrieving the records as it appears to be slower than SQL.

> Took Redis 138ms, Took SQL 105ms

The way I'm retrieving data is the following:

```
return (db.As<MyObject>().Lists["urn:list"].GetAll());
```

Is there any problems with my code above? Is it because of the deserialization that is causing it to be so slower? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever dealing with a remote data store consider using batch methods where possible. e.g. in ServiceStack.Redis you can use the [AddRangeToList](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient_List.cs#L83) to add multiple items to a list.

Each operation in Redis **makes a network call** which you want to optimize as much as possible. There are many batch operations in the RedisClient and it also supports [Pipelining](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineTests.cs) and [Transactions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisTransactions) which are both [pipelined (redis docs)](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) and allows you to batch multiple operations in much fewer socket writes.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. AddRangeToList only accepts List<string> types. Is there a batch method that takes in List<MyClass> ?

Comment: Ultimately everything in redis is stored as bytes (RedisNativeClient), strings are stored in Utf8 (RedisClient) and POCO types are just serialized to JSON before stored as a TPoco -> JSON/string -> bytes (RedisTypedClient). If you want a typed API you need to use a Typed client, e.g. See `RedisClientList<T>.AddRange` https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Generic/RedisClientList.Generic.cs#L176

Comment: got it. thanks again. currently, im doing everything locally, so i guess i wouldn't see much difference whether if i do it in batch or not, right? also, when i look at this [link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#speed), it looks like it takes 132.0076ms to get 3203 records, SQL takes less time to get that many records/objects. any idea why?

Comment: No, using a batch-ful reads/writes matters everytime, each operation translates to socket writes - when its localhost it uses the loopback address but still goes through the TCP stack. Try taking your list of entities and use `StoreAll()` and see how fast it is?